# Running 2 enhanced for loops at the same time

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

Is it possible to have 2 enhanced for loops running at the same time as below?

```
loops1 is a list of integers 1,2,3
loops2 is a list of integers 5,6,7


for(loop1 : loops1 && loop2 : loops2)
{
   System.out.println(loop1 + loop2);
}


Output in a way  : 1 5 2 6 3 7
```

Any input will be helpful.

Thanks !!!

Comment: There is no such construct, because you need to handle the case when the lists are not the same length. What do you want your code to do in this case?

Comment: In case if they are of the same length.

Comment: not possible even same length

Comment: The answer is: No, this is not supported, you can only loop over 1 collection at a time in an enhanced for loop. Reference to the language specification: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2

Comment: Even if you assume same length, you need to define something for the case of different lengths. Use @Eran's answer for that. It stops when the first list ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *is it possible to have 2 enhance for loops running at the same time*

**It's not possible** and i cannot imagine situation when it could be needed. Documentation could be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not possible. You can try to achieve this with iterators :

```
Iterator<Integer> it1 = loops1.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> it2 = loops2.iterator();

while (it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext())
    System.out.println(it1.next()+it2.next());
```

Of course, if the lists don't have the same length, you'll have to decide what to do with the extra integers of the longer list.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. You'd have to have a list of compound values (e.g., where each item has two ints) or some such, or of course use a normal `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. You could try to do a regular for loop and retrieve by index ... Or use java 8 and see If their functional contructs allow You to zip 2 collections, which would end up being just a normal for-each loop in the end.

Answer (score 0):

No.

How would it work when the lists are of different length?

When you compile a for-each loop, the byte code is just a normal for loop with a few extra (hidden) variables. JAD decompiler can be used to verify this.

For example, compiling this:

```
for(String s : list)
    System.out.println(s);
```

will generate equivalent bytecode as this:

```
int length = list.size();
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    String s = list.get(i);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to have 2 enhance for loops running at the same time

**No** it is not possible. **But**

Here you got two list with the same length. Also you want take out put as

```
1 5 2 6 3 7

(First element of list1) (first element of list two)...so on
```

Then you can try as follows

```
 List<Integer> list1=new ArrayList<>();
 List<Integer> list2=new ArrayList<>();
 list1.add(1);
 list1.add(2);
 list1.add(3);
 list2.add(5);
 list2.add(6);
 list2.add(7);
 for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++){ // both list must in equal size
    System.out.print(list1.get(i) + " " + list2.get(i));
    System.out.print(" ");
 }
```

Out put:

```
 1 5 2 6 3 7
```